# Disable user from changing browser tabs

Tags: javascript

I am developing an online examination system,in order to ensure the validity I would really want to prevent the user from visiting any other tabs in the browser during the 1 hour examination session or till the user clicks the submit button(whichever comes first).

I tried to search for this but couldn't find a solution.Hope to receive a solution soon.

Comment: Remebmer that user can open other browser or even open new instance of window :)

Comment: You can't prevent user from switching to new `tab/window`. However there is a work-around to track the same using `window.name` which is by-default  blank, you can assign a value and use it as `token` stored in user's `session`

Comment: You could probably code some complicated history comparison script, but it's probably easier to look into other solutions. If you're in a school you could think of like only running the system on an intranet, or have all non-allowed sites blocked etc. If it's meant to be on the internet, there's no way to prevent users from opening more browsers, use their phone, etc.

Comment: I'd hate to use any web application which does this, very offensive behavior. You'd instead chose to warn them from moving away and let the exam reset/abort if the user still moves out. By the way, you can use the newer [page visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) to detect when the user has moved out.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution to my problem.

Rather than banning the user from visting other **tabs/window** I now detect the user events i.e. if the user is focused on the test window or not.Using Jquery:

```
$(window).blur(function() {
   alert('You are not allowed to leave page blah blah');
   //do something else
});
```

Comment: This isn't remotely reliable.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to stop the user from using their browser. However, you could have the page close or notify you when they move their mouse out of the page or make any non alphanumeric keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent someone from opening other tabs or websites (for very good reason - what if the owners of this site decided you couldn't open  anything else?).

You could consider wrapping your online examination system in a simple Webview, and restrict access to that application only.